# Text on button Zoom

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode9

Random questions. The text on my button in XCode 9 is zooming the text in when I run the application. I took a screenshot of what it is supposed to looked like. The object behind the two buttons is another button with a different background. Is there another object I can put behind the buttons to give it that background, instead of using a blank button. Then how do I get the text to stop zooming in, and yes the buttons are supposed to be rounded.

[image: Buttons]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read a little more books about iOS programming with swift. You shouldn't add buttons as subviews to other buttons... Instead add buttons to `UIView` (orange).

`button.layer.cornerRadius` you are looking for

Whats about zooming? Can't really understand the question, could you add more clarity to it?

Comment: The text looks like it is expanding or zooming in. I already have the corner radius sorted out, thanks for that though! The left is the app running in a sim and the right is the original.

Comment: Looks like expanding? Is it due to animation? What's your code? the text on left has just a little more weight, so is that a problem?

Comment: I don't have code for it currently, it's just the storyboard design. It's a custom font and it just looks slightly bolded. Sorry I'm really OCD haha.